# What is unit of measurement in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

as usual, we use dp for Android and pt(point) for ios as a unit of measurement.

1 pt = 1/72 inch

1 dp = 1/160 inch

But i don't what is unit of measurement in flutter

example:

> SizedBox(height: 16.0)

or

> TextStyle(fontSize: 23.0)

It just a double number, how many dp or pt equal to 1.0 (flutter)? How is it calculated?

Answer (score 19):

From https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Window/devicePixelRatio.html :

> The number of device pixels for each logical pixel. This number might
>   not be a power of two. Indeed, it might not even be an integer. For
>   example, the Nexus 6 has a device pixel ratio of 3.5.
>
> Device pixels are also referred to as physical pixels. Logical pixels
>   are also referred to as device-independent or resolution-independent
>   pixels.
>
> By definition, there are roughly 38 logical pixels per centimeter, or
>   about 96 logical pixels per inch, of the physical display. The value
>   returned by devicePixelRatio is ultimately obtained either from the
>   hardware itself, the device drivers, or a hard-coded value stored in
>   the operating system or firmware, and may be inaccurate, sometimes by
>   a significant margin.
>
> The Flutter framework operates in logical pixels, so it is rarely
>   necessary to directly deal with this property.

Comment: This is the dimensions by google:
mdpi (1x)(Baseline): 160 dpi,
hdpi (1.5x):   240 dpi,
xhdpi (2x):   320 dpi,
xxhdpi 3x:   480 dpi,
xxxhdpi 4x:   640 dpi.
It mean 1 inch has 160dp. If your phone is mdpi, 1 inch has 160 pixel, 
and 240 pixels if it is hdpi v.v...
Back to flutter, following your answer, it means 1 inch has 96 unit (i don't know the name), and the dimensions are:
mdpi: 96 dpi
hdpi: 144 dpi
xhdpi: 192dpi
xxhdpi: 288dpi
xxxhdpi: 384dpi.

Is it right?

Comment: I believe so. You can make a test if you know what is the current size of your screenor device or emulator. Just take MediaQuery.of(context).size and compare

Answer (score 16):

The unit of measure in Flutter is [Logical Pixels](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#where-do-i-store-my-resolution-dependent-image-files). Logical Pixels are equivalent to **cm** or **inches** and do not vary depending on the resolution the same way a ruler doesn't.

1 cm = 38 logical pixels

1 in = 96 logical pixels

Logical pixels are different from device (also called physical) pixels. Device/physical pixels are the number of dots/points in the display that emit light.

This numbers were chosen for historic reasons and come from 1980. Source: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/fontblog/where-does-96-dpi-come-from-in-windows)

Answer (score 7):

It all breaks down to device pixel ratio. For instance:

```
var pixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio; // 2
```

And say you're using `SizedBox` with `height: 10`, like:

```
SizedBox(height: 10); // 10 dp
```

That means your `SizedBox` would be `2 * 10 = 20px` tall on that device.

Comment: 2*10 = 20**px**, since you're multiplying it by device pixel ratio.
10 is the dip (Logical Pixel)

Comment: @Taosif7 Thanks for pointing out.