# Isn't flutter supposed to scale down or up images and text based on the design? Why am I seeing a big difference?

Tags: flutter, resolution, dpi

I have an app that should comply with the design, but the problem I am facing is that the differences in resolutions make the content of the app look small compared to other apps. I have provided a screenshot of 2 different devices (Samsung Galaxy S10 5G and LG X500) and the original Sketch design to show what I am trying to make clear.

My designer is telling me to convert pt to dp to solve the current issue we are facing, but doesn't Flutter do that already? I found a source explaining about this yesterday: [What is unit of measurement in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596099/what-is-unit-of-measurement-in-flutter)

I haven't tried anything else besides the regular implementation way in Flutter, so I am very much confused and stressed.

2 devices:

[image]

original sketch design:

[image]

Text:

```
Text( '\$', 
  style: TextStyle( 
    fontSize: 28, 
    color: Colors.white, 
    fontFamily: 'poppins_light', 
    height: 0.7 
  ), 
),
```

```
Image.asset('assets/images/refresh.png', height:16.0, width: 16.0,),
```

I would like to know if there are more developers who face the same issue as I do right now and what kind of solutions there are to solve the current issue I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is, DP to on screen size is not a constant ratio.

Flutter does use DP, but the specs of the unit makes that it can appear bigger/smaller on different screens.

For that reason you should just use the values provided by your designer and let it be.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> I came with a better alternative to scale up text with the code below (insert inside the MaterialApp widget/root of the code):
>
> ```
> builder: (context, child) {
>  return MediaQuery(
>    child: child,
>    data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.20),
>  );
> },
> ```