# Image dimensions in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter

Emulator screen size is 720 width (720 x 1280: xhdpi). And the image widget dimentions are 200px (height and width).

```
Image(
    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
    image: ...,
),
```

This is how it looks like in the emulator with portrait orientation. How can it be that the image (200px width) is bigger then half of the screen width (720px)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "720" does not mean the number 720 in Flutter dimension system. Say it is a high DPI machine, then the width is actually 720/2.0 (or 2.5 or something like that, I forgot). Thus it is normal for the "200" width image to be this wide.

**EDIT:** Please have a look at this [official doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Window/devicePixelRatio.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596099/what-is-unit-of-measurement-in-flutter). They explain the **unit** of Flutter dimensions quite well.