# How to understand size in Flutter

Tags: flutter

So I want to create a static image `Widget`, and I want the User to be able to adjust its size according to what I've specified, so it's neither too big nor too small.

Let's assume I have a `Widget` like this:

```
Image.network(
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png',
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
)
```

What does the `100` in the `weight` and `height` mean, if converted to `cm` or some other size?
So that I can tell the User by saying, "*please prepare an image with a size of 100x100 cm*"

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596099/what-is-unit-of-measurement-in-flutter), but don't really understand it.
Thank you, please help

Comment: I would say the linked question explains it quite thoroughly. I'm not sure how it could be explained better

Comment: @Ivo yeah, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65687350/9039350) should help clearly, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flutter you almost always work with logical pixels and don't have to care for the rest.

The logical pixels result in mostly the same size on all devices independent from the resolution.

As a rule of thumb 1 cm is around 38 logical pixels and 1 inch is around 96.

So for your `Image` widget, it would be around 2.6cm tall and wide.